# Redirect to a different file from sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have to redirect to `http://www.hostname.com/first/api.php?type=link` when user request for `http://www.hostname.com/first/api/getlink`.

So I tried with following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hostname\.com\/first$

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/getlink$ \/api.php?type=link [L]
```

in a `.htaccess` file and placed inside `first/` folder. I couldn't get the right redirection. But I am getting `404 error`. Could anyone please guide me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which are the dynamic strings?

Comment: Updated! Can you check it now.

Comment: `RewriteRule` must be next to `RewriteCond`. And your hostname regex is wrong, since it includes path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in one .htaccess file in `/first` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !api\.php               [NC]
RewriteRule  ^api/getlink  /first/api.php?type=link  [NC,L]
```

For permanent redirection, replace [NC,L] with [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: What you mean root directory? hostname.com/ or hostname.com/first ?

Comment: Do we have any other possible way that trying at .htaccess in /first folder?

Comment: Do you want the .htaccess file at root (hostname.com/) or at first directory?

Comment: Okay. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Basically means the substitution URL is displayed in the browser's address bar and is permanent. Maybe you want that. If so, just replace the flags as indicated in my answer.